# Sending HTML Template with External CSS and JavaScript to API for PDF Creation

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, httpclient

I have a scenario where I need to send a fully functional HTML template, including external CSS and JavaScript files, to an external API for PDF creation. The API does not have access to the HTML files, and I'm currently using the following C# code:

```
private async Task TalkToPrintServerAsync()
        {
            var appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? throw new SystemException("Could not find executing assembly root");
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var htm = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appRoot, "index.html"), encoding);
            var htmlData = encoding.GetBytes(htm);
            var hashed = htmlData.GetHashCode();
            
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hashed);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7160/PDF", content);
        }
```

Is there an efficient way to read and include external CSS (style.css) and JavaScript (scripts.js) files located in the /assets/ subfolder along with the HTML file and then send the complete set to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. I converted my CSS and JavaScript files into base64 strings and replaced the external links with these encoded strings. While this solution likely requires further investigation into potential concerns and user-related issues, it serves as a temporary fix.

```
private static byte[] GetHTMLTemplateByteArray()
    {
        var appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? throw new SystemException("Could not find executing assembly root");
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var htm = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appRoot, "pdfWrapper", "index.html"), encoding);
        
        var css = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appRoot, "pdfWrapper", "ASSETS", "index-08697c71.css"), encoding);  
        var js = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appRoot, "pdfWrapper", "ASSETS", "index-1924b69c.js"), encoding);

        htm = htm.Replace("./assets/index-1924b69c.js", $"data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(js))}</script>");
        htm = htm.Replace("./assets/index-08697c71.css", $"data:text/css;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css))}");
        return encoding.GetBytes(htm);
    }
```